# IIS session falls instead of web.config configured and IIS settings changed

Tags: session, iis, session-cookies, session-state, session-timeout

We try to extend session timeout. We changed the web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" timeout="60"></sessionState>
```

Also we changed it from IIS settings[image]

What might be missing still less then 20 mins :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application pool idle shutdown timeout has a default value of 20 minutes - meaning if no activity for 20 minutes, the app pool is shutdown to free up resources. You can change this at your application configuration settings.

See [Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

These command examples set the timeout to 1 hour for an application pool named "MyAppPoolName":

PowerShell:

> **Set-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPoolName") -Name processModel.idleTimeout 01:00:00**

Command Line:

> **appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='MyAppPoolName'].processModel.idleTimeout:01:00:00**